# Event observer not working or event not firing

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I have an almost empty magento 1.9.3 project, caches disabled, with 4 custom modules and I want to make an observer in one of them. I made observers before in other projects and they worked, but in this project the observer is not doing anything.

The code is:

```
//App/Code/Local/Feliu/Promos/etc/config.xml

<config>
    <modules>
        <Feliu_Promos>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Feliu_Promos>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <feliu_promos>
                <class>Feliu_Promos_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>feliu_promos_resource</resourceModel>
            </feliu_promos>
            <feliu_promos_resource>
                <class>Feliu_Promos_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <promos>
                        <table>feliu_promos</table>
                    </promos>
                </entities>
            </feliu_promos_resource>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <feliu_promos>
                <class>Feliu_Promos_Block</class>
            </feliu_promos>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <feliu_promos>
                <class>Feliu_Promos_Helper</class>
            </feliu_promos>
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <feliu_promos_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Feliu_Promos</module>
                </setup>
            </feliu_promos_setup>
        </resources>
        <events>
            <controller_front_init_routers>
                <observers>
                    <feliu_promos_model_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>>Feliu_Promos_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>interceptMethod</method>
                    </feliu_promos_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </controller_front_init_routers>
        </events>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Feliu_Promos before="-">Feliu_Promos_Adminhtml_Promos</Feliu_Promos>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <frontend>
    <routers>
        <promotions>
            <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Feliu_Promos_Frontend_Promos</module>
                    <frontName>promotions</frontName>
                </args>
            </promotions>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

and the observer:

```
//App/Code/Local/Feliu/Promos/Model/Observer.php

class Feliu_Promos_Model_Observer
{
    public function interceptMethod($observer) {

        $event = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName();
        Mage::log('**** EVENT FIRED ****' . $event );
        exit(__METHOD__);

    }
}
```

I can't see where is the error, everything seems ok, I read all the previous questions about 'event observer not firing' that I found, but I still can't see the error, maybe it's obvious but I can't see it and the rest of the module is working fine.

PD: I tried to replace the class of the event observer in config.xml from `Feliu_Promos_Model_Observer` to `feliu_promos/observer` but nothing changes.

Comment: There is a typo error in your config.xml. `<class>>Feliu_Promos_Model_Observer</class>` should be `<class>Feliu_Promos_Model_Observer</class>` there is an extra `>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have added ">" in your config.xml from line `<class>>Feliu_Promos_Model_Observer</class>`. Try remove this ">" code and check.

Comment: As I suspected the error was obvious... I lost literally a lot of hours only by one > .... Thank you